# How to hide warnings about ignored attributes in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

How can I disable the following warning in Xcode?

> 'packed' attribute ignored for field of type 'uchar' (aka 'unsigned char')

I browsed through the list of warning switches but couldn't find anything regarding this, also disabled pedantic warnings without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-Wignored-attributes`

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wignored-attributes"
your code
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

You can find a full list on http://fuckingclangwarnings.com/

Comment: The link is dead.